# Need help understanding how to connect an object from different class to main class in Java

Tags: java, class

I'm working on  a project that has two classes.
The main class outputs the data while the other class does all the calculations.
Quick summary: The user inputs a lot of numbers (0-200) and then has to type a letter to stop input and calculate the numbers inputted.

The project that I'm working on says that the other class will have a method

`public boolean inputInformation`

that takes in a Scanner object passed in from main().
For some reason I'm having a brain fart and am having trouble understanding what that means (translating to code).

Extra Q:
my other method 
`public boolean addNumber`
takes in an integer grade <--- what does that mean in code?

Comment: Go through all of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: Ever heard of parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class A{

    public boolean method(int x){
        //do something to x
        return true;
    }

};

Class MainClass{

    public static void Main(){
        A someObject = new A();                     // create an object of class A
        boolean result = someObject.method(5);      // call the method of that object 
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by someObject, is it possible to ask for an example of this?

Comment: someObject is a variable name. I think it would be better if you actually went through a little basic programming. Btw, the snippet of code above is an example of sorts. It has a class called "A" and another class called "MainClass". In your main class, I'm creating an object using class A and calling one of its methods (or functions). This forum will be more helpful if you did some reading on this on your own beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't exactly clear, but I'll take a stab at answering it anyway. I'm guessing you're working on organizing your code through classes in Java. What you've mentioned is very common practice.

"The other class will have a Scanner object passed into it from main". What its asking you to do is create a class 'Scanner' which handles the input related operations in a function, 'inputInformation'. In your main function, create an object of this class and call the method to take in the input.

The 'boolean' return type probably indicates that you have to return true/false based on whether input has ended  or not (by checking for that special character). The query about addNumber refers to the fact that you will be sending an integer to that function as a parameter when calling it.

I think you should try to explain your question more clearly, for anyone to give you a little more advice.

Comment: Eh I guess my question was how do I call a method from a different class and connect it to my main class. Like the main class will output the calculations of the method from the other class.

Answer (score 0):

What it's saying is that you should create a Scanner object in the main() method. Your inputInformation method should take a Scanner object as a parameter, so you'd have to call that method from main() passing your Scanner object to it.

As for your second question, it's saying that it should have a parameter of type 'int'.